# help me get the right answer on this equation!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

y = a + t(x-3), make 'x' the subject

```
y - a = xt - 3t 
y -a + 3t = xt            :divide t on both sides
y -a + 3t/t = x           :this is my answer
```

but the real answer should be

```
x = 3 + y-a/t      :i don't know why the 3 has no 't' in this answer.
```

Comment: You need to divide everything by $t$. Also, $\frac{3t}{t}=3$

Comment: How is this about ordinary differential equations?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y-a=t(x-3)$$
$$\frac{y-a}{t}=x-3$$
$$x=3+\frac{y-a}{t}$$

Comment: thank u so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

$y=a+t(x-3)$

$y=a+tx-3t$

$xt=y-a+3t$

$x=\frac{y-a+3t}{3}$

$x=\frac{y-a}{t}+\frac{3t}{t}$

$x=\frac{y-a}{t}+3$

Comment: thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you wrongly omitted to set parentheses. With these both expressions become equivalent, your 
$$x = (y -a + 3t)/t,$$
and the provided answer
$$x = 3 + (y-a)/t$$